# How to forward (filter) Telegram messages from a private group to myself based on sender?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm in a private Telegram group that has a continual stream of many messages from a large number of people. I need to somehow pull out just those from a handful of specific people, and forward them to myself somehow - e.g. a new group I'm the only member of, or private chat, or some other way (email?). I just need to read them, not reply.

I'm a full stack developer (PHP back end but willing to consider others if works better) and know how to interface with APIs etc so can write some code to do this.

Can anyone advise on what API functions I'd use, or other approach here - and is it the Telegram or Bots API? Or is there a pre-existing solution out there?

Asking here as I've done my own research and not finding any solutions!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bot and put it in the private group. Set the bot as administrator so it can read all messages from all users. For each message the users send in the group, the bot will recive an [update](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) containing a [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object. The message object contains all the information about the message just sent in the group, including the user's data. To filter a message from a specific user you can compare the `user_id` in `$update['message']['from']['id']` with an array containing all the `user_id`s of the users you want to forward their messages to you, with the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) php function passing the `user_id` and the array. Then, if it match, use the [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage) method with these parameters:

```
{
  "chat_id": "YOUR_USER_ID",
  "from_chat_id": "PRIVATE_GROUP_CHAT_ID",
  "message_id": "THE_FILTERED_MESSAGE_ID"
}
```

If you use your `user_id` in the `chat_id` field, the bot will forward the message from the private group to your chat with it. The `from_chat_id` field is the `chat_id` of the private group (you can get it from `$update['message']['chat']['id']`). The `message_id` is the unique identifier for a message in that private group. It's contained in `$update['message']['message_id']`.

Instead of comparing the `user_id` to filter users, you can compare the `first_name`, `last_name` or `username` of the users but only the `user_id` is unique for each user and can not be changed.

---

You are using the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

Comment: @Giolacca9 That's great, thanks - my only problem with that is I don't have control of the private group I'm in, I'm not allowed to add a bot user into it, and I don't have control over who is an administrator. My own personal Telegram account is a regular user in the group (I can read and post), that's all I'm allowed to do. So any solution would have to use my own personal account details to read the messages out from other users. This should be possible, right? As that's what the Telegram client app is doing. Then I guess I can filter the messages as you suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: It is possible to do that but it's very difficult. You should use te [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api)